# Store cursor position in class object (ncurses c++)

Tags: c++, class, struct, position, ncurses

I am using QTCreator to compile my c++ code and the `<curses.h>` library.

Let us say we have the following class definition (.h):

```
struct coordinateYX
{
    int y;
    int x;

    coordinateYX(long int yPos, long int xPos);
    coordinateYX() {}
}

class Rogue
{
private:
    long int health;
    coordinateYX heroPosition;
public:
    long int getHealth();
    void setHealth(long int initHealth);
    void healthChange(long int vDelta);
    coordinateYX getHeroPosition();
    void setHeroPosition(coordinateYX hPos);
};
```

and (.cpp):

```
coordinateYX::coordinateYX(long int yPos, long int xPos) : y{yPos}, x{xPos} {}

long int Rogue::getHealth() {return health;}
void Rogue::setHealth(long int initHealth) {health = initHealth;}
void Rogue::healthChange(long int vDelta) {health += vDelta;}
coordinateYX Rogue::getHeroPosition() {return heroPosition;}
void Rogue::setHeroPosition(coordinateYX hPos)
{
    heroPosition.y = hPos.y;
    heroPosition.x = hPos.x;
}
```

In my main.cpp, I am trying to store the current cursor position into an instantiation of Rogue:

```
Rogue Hero;
getyx(stdscr, Hero.getHeroPosition().y, Hero.getHeroPosition().x);
```

But I always get an error:

```
using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]
```

It also shows this below as part of the error which is in the `<curses.h>` file

```
#define getyx(w, y, x)     (y = getcury(w), x = getcurx(w))
```

Although I can simply store these values in another struct initialized in `main.cpp`, how can I store the x and y positions directly in the class data members?

Thank you.

Comment: @drescherjm My apologies. I have edited the original post with the correct error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to change `getHeroPosition` to return a reference instead of value:

```
coordinateYX& Rogue::getHeroPosition() {return heroPosition;}
```

The problem is here you are trying to assign to the `Rogue` position:

```
getyx(stdscr, Hero.getHeroPosition().y, Hero.getHeroPosition().x);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Hero.getHeroPosition().y = getcury(stdscr);
Hero.getHeroPosition().x = getcurx(stdscr);
```

But `getHeroPosition` returns the position by value (it returns a copy, an rvalue). If you assign a value to that temporary copy it will just be lost. The solution is to assign to a reference to the actual `Rogue` position (an lvalue).

Alternatively, you can use your existing `setPosition` function:

```
coordinateYX position;
getyx(stdscr, position.X, position.Y);
Hero.setPosition(position);
```

Comment: Thank you! The return alias seems to solve my problem. However, now I won't actually be able to get the value since `print(playerCoordinate, Hero.getHeroPosition().y);` (where the print function just prints an int at a coordinate.) does not work. Any solutions, so my get function can be used both ways? I tried overloading but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What error do you get? I can't think why it shouldn't. You could use my alternative solution instead.